# jakarta.faces.application.viewexpiredexception when a new tab is open (inter war file communication)

Tags: jsf, viewexpiredexception

I have multi JSF front ends each running in a different war file (same host different ports), when a view scoped bean is open in tab 1, and a new tab to another war file is open, the view in the first tab expires.

Thanks